# Почему ошибка в jQuery методе change при выводе значения на представление?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Есть следующий код, но данные на представлении не выводятся. Проблема где-то в jQuery. Где ошибка?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#IdSize').change(function () {
            var idS = $('#IdSize').val();
            var urlPrice = '@Url.Action("GetPriceForSize")';
            $.post(urlPrice, {
                idProd: '@Model.Product.IdProduct',
                idSize: idS
            }, function (data) {
                if (data.ok) {
                    $('.price').html(data.data);
                } else {
                    window.alert('error:' + data.message);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetPriceForSize(int idProd, int idSize) {
    try {
        Prices price = repository.Prices.
        Where(p = > p.IdProd == idProd && p.IdSize == idSize).
        SingleOrDefault();

        return Json(new {
            ok = true, price = price.Price, message = ""
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Json(new {
            ok = false, message = e.Message
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Firebug`ом или ему подобными вещами не пробовали пользоваться?

Comment: Пробовал. Заходит в function(data), а потом сразу в конец функции. Т.е. через саму функцию не проходит.